# How to use geometry data type as a parameter in asyncpg?

Tags: python, postgresql, bounding-box, asyncpg

For context, I want to query something to the effect of:

```
select point '(1,1)' <@ box '((0,0),(2,2))';
```

I tried something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (latlng POINT NOT NULL);

box = [[22.268764039073968, -140.09765625000003], [61.438767493682825, -56.42578125000001]]
await pool.fetch(f'SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE latlng <@ $1;', box)
```

Then I tried this:

```
from asyncpg.types import Point, Box

v = [[22.268764039073968,-140.09765625000003],[61.438767493682825,-56.42578125000001]]
box = Box(Point(v[0][0], v[0][1]), Point(v[1][0], v[1][1]))
await pool.fetch(f'SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE latlng <@ $1;', box)
```

Both attempts result in the error:

```
asyncpg.exceptions.AmbiguousFunctionError: operator is not unique: point <@ unknown
HINT:  Could not choose a best candidate operator. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

I'm guessing that I have to manually make asyncpg use [box_encode()](https://github.com/MagicStack/py-pgproto/blob/76091445db8b49a7d78504b47eb34fcbfbb89567/codecs/geometry.pyx#L35) for this parameter (since it's not implied by any table definition), but how do I tell asyncpg to do that?

Comment: You need to cast the argument to the box type: `SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE latlng <@ $1::box;`.  Postgres can infer the type of the argument in most cases, but not in this query, evidently.

Comment: It works, thank you!

Comment: If your question was answered please mark it as [solved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: @IonutTicus done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Repeating the answer given in Elvis's comment above so I can mark the question as solved)

The solution is to add `::box` after the arg to [cast](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS) it, like so:

```
box = [[22.268764039073968, -140.09765625000003], [61.438767493682825, -56.42578125000001]]
await pool.fetch(f'SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE latlng <@ $1::box;', box)
```